# Set initial value to a Toggle of a form in Angular Material within HTML

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, toggle

I am working with a simple form:

**HTML**

```
<mat-card>
  <form (submit)="onAddBet(betForm)" #betForm="ngForm">
    <mat-form-field>
      <textarea #description="ngModel" matInput rows="6" placeholder="Description" name="description" ngModel
        required></textarea>
      <mat-error *ngIf="description.invalid">Please enter a Bet Description</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-slide-toggle #privacy="ngModel" name="privacy" ngModel>Private</mat-slide-toggle>
    <mat-slide-toggle #comments="ngModel" name="comments" ngModel>Allow comments</mat-slide-toggle>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">
      CREATE
    </button>
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

If I press submit without touching any field of the form I get all the fields empty as it should be expected but I would like to get instead of the status of the form, meaning all the fields as `""` but in the fields "privacy" and "comments" as false (boolean) (the default appearance of the toggles is as not marked).

I know that this could be easily done by Typescript from the component following the method:

**Typescript**

```
onAddBet(form: NgForm) {
    if (!form.value.privacy) {
      form.value.privacy = false;
      console.log(form.value);
    } else console.log(form.value);
    if (form.invalid) return;
    form.resetForm();
  }
```

But I was wondering if there is any `HTML` attribute to run the same code avoiding to use `Typescript`

How could I do it?

Comment: Can you provide your component code as well?

Comment: Sure. Actually, I have rephrased my question in order to get the exact answer that I was expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize your `ngModel` in your HTML by using `ngModel` with a one-way binding

```html
<mat-slide-toggle #privacy="ngModel" name="privacy" [ngModel]="false">Private</mat-slide-toggle>
<mat-slide-toggle #comments="ngModel" name="comments" [ngModel]="false">Allow comments</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Then in your component

```js
onAddBet(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form.value);
    if (form.invalid) return;
    form.resetForm();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of [slide-toggle](https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/api) you can use [checked]="checked" in HTML.

Comment: `[checked]` does not set the slide-toggle when `ngModel` is used